# Login Page without Bultin Login System Django

Tags: django

I have a model called Van that have 2 fields: Plate and Password. I should use this informations to login in a frontend system (not django admin).

Searching on the internet i just found example using Bultin Login System but i need a custom login using only Van model.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Django has a documentation page on custom login systems: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/

Comment: Thanks @WillemVanOnsem i think this is enought

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement custom [authorization backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#handling-authorization-in-custom-backends).

For example you can modify this:

from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend

```
class EmailAuthBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(email=username)
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            # Run the default password hasher once to reduce the timing
            # difference between an existing and a non-existing user (#20760).
            User().set_password(password)
```